# как заставить setInterval работать с динамической переменной

Tags: javascript

```
//
var update_time        = 1*1000;
var count_request_base = 2;
var count_request      = count_request_base;

function my_function(){
    count_request--;
    if(count_request>0){
    }else{
        update_time    = update_time*2;
        count_request  = count_request_base;
    }
    console.log('update time: '+(update_time/1000)+'s, count request:' + count_request);
}

setInterval(my_function, update_time);
```

запускаю код выше, все как ожидал

```
(index):41 update time: 1s, count request:1
(index):41 update time: 2s, count request:2
(index):41 update time: 2s, count request:1
(index):41 update time: 4s, count request:2
(index):41 update time: 4s, count request:1
(index):41 update time: 8s, count request:2
(index):41 update time: 8s, count request:1
(index):41 update time: 16s, count request:2
(index):41 update time: 16s, count request:1
(index):41 update time: 32s, count request:2
(index):41 update time: 32s, count request:1
```

Проблема: в консоли все как надо, но переменная update_time в setInterval как была 1 секунду, так и остается 1 секунду. Хотя она умножается на 2 в процессе запуска функции

Вопрос: как заставить setInterval работать с динамической переменной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С `setInterval` так не получится, нельзя менять интервал времени уже запущенного `setInterval`.

Можно использовать `setTimeout`.

Пример.

```js
var update_time = 1 * 1000;
var count_request_base = 2;
var count_request = count_request_base;

function my_function() {
  count_request--;
  if (count_request > 0) {} else {
    update_time = update_time * 2;
    count_request = count_request_base;
  }
  console.log('update time: ' + (update_time / 1000) + 's, count request:' + count_request);
  setTimeout(my_function, update_time);
}

setTimeout(my_function, update_time);
```

Comment: То что надо! Даже не придется много переделывать