# Timeout в цикле JS

Tags: javascript

Вот пример кода на JS, **таймаут не работает** как надо. Все, что внутри него **срабатывает одновременно**, а не откладывается на `speed` миллисекунд. Как мне переделать код чтобы действия в таймауте откладывалось на `speed` миллисекунд?

```
          for (let i = parseInt(balloon.style.left); i > 0; i--) {
       
            var speed = i/parseInt(theCSSprop)*100;
                speed = Math.floor(speed);
                speed = Math.abs(speed - 100);
          
            setTimeout(() => {
                let tmp = parseInt(balloon.style.left) - 1;
                balloon.style.left = tmp.toString() + "px";
                
            }, speed);
        };
```

Comment: сделайте let speed

Comment: не помогло, эффекта нет

Comment: Оформите в песочницу вопрос. Порешаем

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно конечно полностью, но может так хотели?

```js
let theCSSprop = 5;
balloon.style.left = "1000px";
let speed = 0;
let initialState = parseInt(balloon.style.left)/theCSSprop|0;

for (let i = 0; i < initialState; i++) {
        speed += i;        
    setTimeout(() => {        
        console.log(balloon.style.left);   
        let tmp = parseInt(balloon.style.left) - theCSSprop;
        balloon.style.left = tmp.toString() + "px";
    }, speed);
};
```

```css
.circ {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bordeR: 5px solid tomato;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="balloon" class="circ">
  
</div>
```

Comment: У меня еще скорость зависит от того, насколько близко к правой стенке шар - чем ближе - тем сильнее отталкивается. Но таймаут у Вас работает да, так как и нужно. Пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: Странно, у вас работает как надо. `Console.log` выводит постепенно изменяющееся значение balloon.style.left. А у меня просто сразу выводятся все значения и фигура уже стоит у левой стенки. То есть моментально всё срабатывает. Разницы в коде нет

Comment: Странно конечно. Но Ваш код полностью нам недоступно. Ищите может кто переопределил setTimeout. или вы что не договариваете

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос: как сделать чтобы `speed` который подается в `setTimeout` был изменяемым. То есть скорость движения фигуры была динамическая? Например чтобы каждую секунду круг замедлялся? (то есть значение `speed` увеличивалось)

Comment: Да хороший вопрос. Сам пытаюсь воспроизвести

Comment: (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882972/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-setinterval-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9) есть ответ на stackoverflow, но виснет при рекурсивном вызове settimeout :/

Comment: Чуток изменил код может поможет